How to microwave amaranth?
Can I microwave this grain?
I usually microwave my porridge oats so I want something equally as convenient. I picked up some amaranth but I can't find much online about microwaving it.
Any advice on how to microwave 1/4 cup of amaranth would be much appreciated.

I ended up cooking 50 g of amaranth with 187.5 ml of water at 3 minute intervals in a 900 W microwave, it took a total of 12 minutes for the water to be fully absorbed and for the grain to become a solid almost translucent color. I also left it to rest for 10 minutes afterwards to trap any moisture that would otherwise steam off.
It was a little drier than I expected, I may try lowering the time of the last interval, but this might just be how amaranth is as I am not experienced with the grain.
It definitely made a nice porridge like breakfast once mixed with soy milk, fruit and nuts.

Good for you and thanks for the reply. If you want, you’ll find information about merging your accounts here.

Sounds like you boiled off a lot of the liquid - try using less water and see how it goes.

WikiHow has a recipe for 3 minute Amaranth microwave porridge.
Basically, it's the same process as for oats with an adjustment of the liquid volumes to suit the grain. For the amaranth they seem to use 1 & 1/6th cups of liquid per cup of grain, whereas microwave porridge oats tend to use 2:1 liquid: grain, so the amaranth uses less liquid.
You might need to adjust the time microwaved by a bit if only using 1/4 cup of amaranth, but it won't be much less as you still need to cook the grain itself. It might be 2.5 min rather than 3 min, as 1/4 cup will heat faster than 1 cup.
